# How to print every third element from current index in list of elements

Tags: python

I have list of elements `lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']`. How to print every third elements from current index in following format? `[[ 'A', 'E', 'I'],[ 'B', 'F', 'J'],[ 'C', 'G'],[ 'D', 'H']]`:

```
def printFormat(lst, columns):
  for i in range(0, len(lst)):
    print lst[i]
    for j in range():
    #if (i)%3==0:
    #    print lst[i]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
    columns = 3
    printFormat(lst, columns)
```

Comment: Related to [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: Your requested output is not every third element, it's every fourth (4 increments between A and E for example)

Comment: @Evert Ah, I believe you're right. I'll modify my comment saying it's related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> lst
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
>>> num_of_parts=4
>>> newlst=[lst[i::4] for i in range(num_of_parts)]
>>> newlst
[['A', 'E', 'I'], ['B', 'F', 'J'], ['C', 'G'], ['D', 'H']]
>>>
```

**Edit 1 :** adding some explanation and 2nd method that uses the mod operator

`list_obj[start:stop:step]` is similar to the method `slice(start, stop, step)`. `start` indicates from where slicing must start and the slicing stops at `stop - 1`. If `start` and `stop` are ignored, they are replaced by `0` and `len(list) - 1` respectively.

Hence `start` and `stop` are meant to get a sublist/slice of the list and `step` gets every `step` (every 2nd/3rd etc) element from that sublist/slice.

Here are some examples demonstrating the same:

```
>>> lst
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> lst[1:3]
[1, 2]
>>> lst[1:]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> lst[:3]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> lst[::2]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> lst[::1]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> lst[1::2]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>>
```

Mod operator method:

```
>>> lst
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
>>> num_of_parts=4
>>> newlst=[[lst[i] for i in range(len(lst)) if i%4 == j] for j in range(num_of_parts)]
>>> newlst
[['A', 'E', 'I'], ['B', 'F', 'J'], ['C', 'G'], ['D', 'H']]
>>>
```

**Edit 2 :** Making the mod operator method more readable we get the following:

```
>>> lst=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J']
>>> newlst=[]
>>> for j in range(num_of_parts):
...     temp=[]
...     for i in range(len(lst)):
...             if i%4 == j:
...                     temp.append(lst[i])
...     newlst.append(temp)
... 
>>> newlst
[['A', 'E', 'I'], ['B', 'F', 'J'], ['C', 'G'], ['D', 'H']]
>>>
```

Comment: And now with your edit my answer is useless hahah, jokes aside, as always good readable answer providing `num_of_parts` variable.

Comment: @ritesht93 can we do the same operation using mod operator?

Comment: Can you or someone please explain also how the `::` syntax works? To someone who's never seen this before, it looks confusing. I'd prefer a full explanation rather than magic code.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar hehe yeah

Comment: @shanky yes it is doable with mod operator too, let me come up with something

Comment: @darksky it is similar to the `slice` method which takes 3 parameters: start, stop and step. From the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#slice

Comment: @shanky Thanks. Naturally, `number_of_parts` here should be `len(lst)`.

Comment: @shanky added another method that uses the mod operator

Comment: @shanky made the mod operator method more readable/understandable

Comment: @ritesht93 The number of sublists we want is equal to the `len(lst)` because there are exactly that many elements in the list to start a sublist from.

Comment: @darksky no, if we put `num_of_parts` as equal to `len(lst)` then the result will have initial values as the answer but there will be more sublists added into the result which is not what is desired.

Comment: @darksky `[lst[i::4] for i in range(len(lst))]` gives the output as `[['A', 'E', 'I'], ['B', 'F', 'J'], ['C', 'G'], ['D', 'H'], ['E', 'I'], ['F', 'J'], ['G'], ['H'], ['I'], ['J']]`. Notice that initial 4 elements correspond to our answer but there are more sublist added too. And if you see the number of sublist then that is equal to the number of elements present in the list i.e 10

Comment: Exactly. Unless OP needs only the first four.

Comment: Have a look at the code OP wrote up there: `for i in range(0, len(lst)):`. I think this might indicate he/she might be interested in them all.

Comment: @darksky yes. and also I noticed that the question had been edited wrongly missing the ending brackets in the output. Corrected the question. Ohh and regarding the loop you mentioned, OP used that because he wanted to code the solution using `mod` operator

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148949/discussion-between-darksky-and-ritesht93).

Comment: @darksky anyways I think OP accepted the answer and  Thanks for pointing the different result as well :)

Comment: Sure. I think It was ambiguous precisely because the ending bracket was missing :)

Answer (score 3):

A one-liner solution is:

```
>>> [lst[i::4] for i in range(4)]
[['A', 'E', 'I'], ['B', 'F', 'J'], ['C', 'G'], ['D', 'H']]
```